# Defunct processes in Docker container

Tags: python, linux, docker, containers, supervisord

I have a Docker container in which I am running a Python Flask API with GUnicorn and a server process, also written in Python. This server processes spawns long-running child processes and waits for them (one observation thread per child process). The root process is `tini`. This runs `supervisord`, which in turn spawns GUnicorn and the server process. The processes spawned by the server process are using multiple threads.

Sometimes, I observe defunct processes appearing in the process list. To counter this problem, I originally introduced `tini` as root process, but apparently, this is not enough.

As far as I understand, defunct processes are processes, which have been terminated, but not yet collected by their parent process. However, my server process specifically `join`s its child processes (using threads) and I would assume, GUnicorn and `supervisord` do the same.

How can I determine where these defunct processes are coming from and how can I debug/handle this problem?

Comment: What's the result if not use `tini`, just add `--init` when run the container?

Comment: Unfortunately, my deployment environment does not support an `--init` flag as far as I know. Therefore, I included `tini` into the container.

Comment: You shouldn't need both tini and supervisord (I'd prefer only tini if that's an option).  If the parent process is still running, though, it needs to wait(2) for its children process to exit; only if the parent process exits do children get reassigned to the init process.

Comment: Actually, when I was only using supervisord, I also observed those defunct processes. That's why I introduced tini in the first place. I think I need supervisord because I want to run multiple processes in the container. My processes `join` the child processes. Isn't that similar to wait(2)?